# taking specific json dictionary and parsing it in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, parsing

i need to take this "Data" block from .json file:

```
                    {
                        "Info": {
                            "type": "audi",
                            "cost": "3435$"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Info": {
                            "type": "bmw",
                            "cost": "7766$"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Info": {
                            "type": "ford",
                            "cost": "8766$"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Info": {
                            "type": "kia",
                            "cost": "1123$"
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

and parse it in jscript to receive string like this:
**audi;3435$;bmw;7766$;ford;8766$;kia;1123$;...type_n value;cost_n value;**

I have a problem with taking specific data from the .json file and correct parsing.
I will be very grateful for any tips

Comment: JSON.parse(your text) will get it into javascript. Then you can manipulate it to get the data you want. Best way to get help here is to try and do this yourself first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and generate the string with the format `type_n;const_n`

```js
const data = [
 {
     "Info": {
  "type": "audi",
  "cost": "3435$"
     }
 },
 {
     "Info": {
  "type": "bmw",
  "cost": "7766$"
     }
 },
 {
      "Info": {
  "type": "ford",
  "cost": "8766$"
     }
 },
 {
     "Info": {
  "type": "kia",
  "cost": "1123$"
     }
 }
];

const parsedStr = data.reduce((str, {Info:{type, cost}}) => (str += `${type};${cost};`), '');

console.log(parsedStr);
```